# How can i get exact google map latitude and longitude in php?

Tags: php, google-api, google-map

How can i get exact *Latitude* and *longitude* of user in php, without using IP,
Any hope with **google api**?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this about PHP and it has anything to do with Magento.

Answer (score 8):

By using the district name you can get the exact latitude and longitude. Please follow the below code:

```
$address = $_POST['district'];//here we can get the name of the district
$geo = file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' . urlencode($address) . '&sensor=false');
// We convert the JSON to an array
$geo = json_decode($geo, true);
// If everything is cool
if ($geo['status'] == 'OK') {
    // We set our values
    $latitude = $geo['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
    $longitude = $geo['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
    $resultjson = ['success' => 'OK', 'latitude' => $latitude, 'longtitude' => $longitude];
    echo json_encode($resultjson);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get **latitude** and **longitude** by **address**

```
$address = '1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA';
$coordinates = file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' . urlencode($address) . '&sensor=true');
$coordinates = json_decode($coordinates);
$latitude = $coordinates->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$longitude = $coordinates->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
```

Answer (score 3):

***please try this code, hope it's helpful for you***

```
<?php
// Address
$address = 'BTM 2nd Stage, Bengaluru, Karnataka 560076';
// Get JSON results from this request
$geo = file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.urlencode($address).'&sensor=false');

// Convert the JSON to an array

$geo = json_decode($geo, true);

if ($geo['status'] == 'OK') {
  // Get Lat & Long
  $latitude = $geo['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
  $longitude = $geo['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
}
?>
```

> For more info, please have a look following URLs:-
>   [Get Latitude and Longitude from Address using Google Maps API and PHP](http://www.codexworld.com/get-latitude-longitude-from-address-using-google-maps-api-php/)